# Rule not fired after update statement in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, rules

Following the guide in [www.postgresql.org](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/rules-update.html)

I created this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE shoelace_log (
sl_name    text,          -- shoelace changed
sl_avail   integer,       -- new available value
log_who    text,          -- who did it
log_when   timestamp      -- when);
CREATE RULE log_shoelace AS ON UPDATE TO shoelace_data
WHERE NEW.sl_avail <> OLD.sl_avail
DO INSERT INTO shoelace_log VALUES (
                                NEW.sl_name,
                                NEW.sl_avail,
                                current_user,
                                current_timestamp
                            );
```

When i try to execute the query in pgAdmin3 query console:

```
UPDATE shoelace_data SET sl_avail = 6 WHERE sl_name = 'sl7';
```

Only the update query are executed, and the rule isn't fired. I try to use the command EXPLAIN to understand why.

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE shoelace_log SET sl_avail = 6 WHERE sl_name = 'sl7';
```

The log says:

```
"Seq Scan on shoelace_log  (cost=0.00..19.66 rows=4 width=32)"
"  Filter: (sl_name = 'sl7'::text)"
"Seq Scan on shoelace_log  (cost=0.00..19.62 rows=4 width=78)"
"  Filter: (sl_name = 'sl7'::text)"
```

I also try to use VERBOSE option with EXPLAIN, but i can't understand why my event isn't trigged.

Comment: I tried to run the sample you linked to on pg9 and have same issue.

Comment: You say your pgAdmin3 query is UPDATE *shoelace_data*, but you EXPLAIN UPDATE *shoelace_log* (the log table) ... are you sure you're typing the query you think you're typing?

Answer (score 3):

You have chosen wrong feature. Forget rules altogether — they're very hard, almost impossible to do right.

What you need here is a trigger:

```
create or replace function shoelace_log_who_when()
returns trigger language plpgsql as
$$
begin
  if OLD.sl_avail is distinct from NEW.sl_avail then
    NEW.log_who = current_user;
    NEW.log_when = current_timestamp;
  end if;
  return NEW;
end;
$$;

create trigger shoelace_log_who_when before update on shoelace_log
  for each row execute procedure shoelace_log_who_when();
```

Try it:

```
insert into shoelace_log values ( 'foo', 1, NULL, NULL );
select * from shoelace_log;
```

```
sl_name | sl_avail | log_who | log_when 
---------+----------+---------+----------
foo     |        1 |         |
```

```
update shoelace_log set sl_avail=2;
select * from shoelace_log;
```

```
 sl_name | sl_avail | log_who  |         log_when          
---------+----------+----------+---------------------------
 foo     |        2 | tometzky | 2011-03-30 17:06:21.07137
```

Comment: +1 For nice answer, but still doesn't explain why such a simple example doesn't work.

Comment: That's why you should not use rules. They're so complicated, that even seasoned Postgres users would not try to explain their behavior. I think they're considered for throwing out of Postgres &mdash; with INSTEAD OF triggers on views in 9.1 they're not needed anymore for anything.

Comment: Too bad the pg docs don't state that you shouldn't use them.  I have read a few reasons why they are pain and should be avoided, but not because they don't function as the docs describe.

Comment: The OP has mixed up the *data* and *log* tables - he wants to INSERT into the latter when the former is UPDATEd in a certain way.  You'll want a different trigger procedure for that.  (Re-read the question, stopping just before the EXPLAIN mixes things up...)

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to consider using the pre-built addon that does that for you:

http://pgfoundry.org/projects/tablelog/

Comment: It is not tablelog. It was meant just to fill in automatic last modified timestamp and user in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the example, and it worked. But I had to create the shoelace_data table first. That table isn't in the example.

```
create table shoelace_data (
    sl_name text,
    sl_avail integer
);
insert into shoelace_data values ('Catcall', 3);
update shoelace_data set sl_avail = 5;
```

Now if you select from the *log* table . . .

```
select * from shoelace_log;
"Catcall";5;"postgres";"2011-03-31 20:40:10.906"
```

Note carefully that the rule says to insert into **shoelace_log** when there's an update to the **sl_avail** column in **shoelace_data**.